Gunicorn ModuleNotFoundError when migrating from flask
I have a Flask app with the (simplified) organisation as follows:
.
└── app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── api
    │   └── v1.py
    ├── main.py
    └── start.sh

init.py:
# app/__init__.py
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

main.py:
from app.api.v1 import v1
from app import application

application.register_blueprint(v1, url_prefix='/api/v1')

@application.route("/")
def default():
    return 'Hello World!'

I launch it via start.sh: flask --app main.py run. Imports in all py files are made as such: from app.XXX import YYY
I am now trying to use gunicorn, so the start.sh looks like this: gunicorn --workers=3 main:application.
I then receive the error message:
File "/app/main.py", line 10, in <module>
     from app.api.v1 import v1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

What I do not understand is that the modules were well managed by flask, but now they break. Do I need to remove all the app. prefixes in my imports? Why?
Edit: all of this runs within a Docker container so I do not think this is a case of incorrect gunicorn installation.

you can shell into container to check workdir.  It look like set workdir incorrect in dockerfile

The workdir seems correct (docker exec -it bash goes to /app), I have found that starting gunicorn with cd .. & gunicorn --workers=3 app.main:application works normally with all the includes. However I still need to change the relative path of the elements in my config file
